# How can we define constant scalar curvature Kahler or cscK on pair $(X,D)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, geometric-analysis

A Kahler metric $\omega$
with cone singularities along divisor
$D$
with cone angle $2\pi\beta$
is said to be
of
constant scalar curvature Kahler
or
cscK
if its scalar curvature $S(\omega)$,  which is a well-defined
smooth function on $X\setminus D$
, satisfies
$S(\omega) = const$ on
$X\setminus
D$.

For the definition of Kahler Einstein metric with positive first chern class on $X\setminus D$ we have $Ric(\omega)=\omega$ on $X\setminus D$

But on pair $(X,D)$ we add the current of integration $[D]$ i.e.,

$$Ric(\omega)=\omega+[D]$$

My question is how can we define constant scalar curvature Kahler
or
cscK on pair $(X,D)$

Comment: I don't see a reasonable way to define the scalar curvature over $D$ (say e.g. as a distribution), even in the model case of $(\mathbb{C},0)$ with the standard cone metric $|z|^{2(\beta-1)}idz\wedge d\overline{z}$.

Answer (score 1):

This question is discussed in detail by Long Li in "Subharmonicity of conic Mabuchi's functional, I", available at arXiv:1511.00178. In section 2 he proposes two definitions, one called conic cscK and the other called "strong" conic cscK.